# List all files in a drive not equal amount?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to list all files in drive C and wrote the following function:

```
void Class_fileHandler::FindAllFiles(wstring FolderName)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    wstring searchFolderName(FolderName);

    searchFolderName.append(TEXT("\\*.*"));
    HANDLE FirstFile = FindFirstFile(&searchFolderName[0], &findData);

    while (FindNextFile(FirstFile, &findData))
    {
        // Thanks to Collin Dauphinee
        if (((findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)  /**&& (findData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)**/)
        {
            m_fileQueuer.push_back(findData.cFileName);
        }
        else if (wcscmp(findData.cFileName, TEXT(".")) && wcscmp(findData.cFileName, TEXT("..")))
        {
            wstring NewPath = FolderName + TEXT("\\") +  findData.cFileName;
            FindAllFiles(NewPath);
        }
    }
}

void Class_fileHandler::testfunc()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_driveLetters.size(); ++i)
    {
        // At the moment there is only C:
        // So the function call is:
        // FindAllFiles(TEXT("C:"))
        FindAllFiles(m_driveLetters[i]);
    }

    wofstream file("C:\\tmp\\all_files.txt");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<m_fileQueuer.size(); i++)
        file << m_fileQueuer[i] << endl;
    file.close();
```

All filenames are written into C:\tmp\all_files.txt.
This file contains about 168.000 lines/filenames.

When I select the whole drive C: and click on properties, it shows 580.000 files.
[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are missing the first file. You call `FindFirstFile` then you immediately call `FindNextFile`. Use this instead: `FindFirstFile(); do{...}while(`FindNextFile`);` --- Also add error check and close the handle when finished `if (FirstFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){... FindClose(FirstFile);}`

Comment: Thanks, I improved that aswell!

Comment: You should examine why FindNextFile finishes, if its not NO_MORE_FILES you skipped a directory, probably due to permissions. GetLastError will tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dwFileAttributes` member contains bit flags. Your code is checking if a directory's attributes *only* has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` bit set; it won't traverse into directories that have additional bits set, such as `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM`.

The correct check should be `((findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)`, which essentially pulls out the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` bit and checks if it's set.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Now I get 190.000 files. That was a big mistake, but still way to few files. Any other ideas?

Comment: Append `*` instead of `*.*` to the search path. You also may not have permissions to list some folders, but I believe they show up in the summary.

Comment: * or \*.\* makes no difference here. I believe it has something to do with permissions then. Thanks anyway!